# Correct Compilation

Tags: java, compilation

I have an existential question, I have a project that has some errors and it marks some packages in red, I wonder if when compiling these affect my .class files that will later be uploaded to the webapps folder where I have my program deployed?
Thank you.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red usually means compilation errors, which means that if you didn't compile them earlier there are no class files to affect (because they don't even exist) and if you did compile earlier it means that those class files will be outdated.

In other words, your mission is to not have compiler errors to begin with, not wondering how it will affect existing compilation artifacts.